# How to omit xml declaration in WordML document.xml when working with bytes and MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, wordml

I have 2 snippets of code which work differently

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
           WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"D:\Tests\WordML\ML_Example.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            // Add a main document part. 
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("SimpleTextExample.xml");
            mainPart.Document = new Document(tr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Here it works great and generates .docx good.

Now second way of making it with bytes and MemoryStream-uri.

```
 MemoryStream modeleRootStream = new MemoryStream();
```

XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
                                                   {
                                                       OmitXmlDeclaration = true
                                                   };
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(modeleRootStream, writerSettings);

```
        initialXml.WriteTo(xmlWriter);

        xmlWriter.Flush();

        modeleRootStream.Position = 0;
       MemoryStream streamWithWord = new MemoryStream();

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(streamWithWord,
            WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            // Add a main document part. 
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

            string streamContent = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(modeleRootStream))
            {
               streamContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            mainPart.Document = new Document(streamContent);
        }

        byte[] wordDocBytes = streamWithWord.GetBuffer();

        streamWithWord.Close();

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Tests\WordML\ML_Example1.docx", wordDocBytes);
```

When you make it 2nd way the generated document is not good. In it's document.xml you're gonna see xml declaration. The initialXml represents XElement of initial WordML xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

....

And when you try to open it in Word it gives you the message that the file is truncated.

How can I use bytes and MemoryStreams and not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
byte[] wordDocBytes = streamWithWord.GetBuffer();
```

That should be:

```
byte[] wordDocBytes = streamWithWord.ToArray();
```

`GetBuffer` returns the *extra* part of the buffer - not just the valid data.

You can usually omit xml headers with `XmlWriterSettings`.

It is almost certainly to do the write more directly, but I'm about to run out of signal (on the train...).